# A single function that can be invoked in two ways

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a single function that can be invoked in two ways:

```
sum(3,5); //8
```

OR

```
sum(3)(5); //8
```

This is aparently not enough:

```
function sum (a,b){
  return a + b;
}
```

Here is where I am so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/marcusdei/a8tds42d/1/

Comment: Firstly, why on earth would you want to do that?

Comment: because there are apparently people who do it this way..

Comment: Then it seems your first solution would be to ask them not to.

Comment: The second format seems like such an odd construct in the javascript world that I would think of it as a non-starter.  I don't think any developer that is reasonably versed in js would want that sort of a function signature.

Comment: @MikeBrant It's just currying essentially. It's useful in the functional paradigm and this seems like homework.

Comment: @MikeBrant: for a function called `sum`, yeah, it definitely weird, but functions returning other functions that you can then call with more arguments isn't that uncommon. `someFunction(someargs)(somemoreargs)`. More common, and arguably more readable, would be a chaining syntax `someObj.someFunction(someArgs).someOtherFunction(someMoreArgs)`

Comment: well I'm glad we all learned something then .. this is not homework, I'm learning JS for my career

Comment: @MattBurland I would agree that the chaining approach is much more common to javascript, though currying is something that can have its place.  Since the OP noted they are just learning javascript, I would argue that unless there is some specific need for currying, they should focus on more common development patterns in js and master those.  That would help provide insight to cases where currying is a practical solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
function sum (a,b){
    if(b == undefined){
        return function(b){
            return a + b;   
        }
    } else {
      return a + b;        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why aside (*why would you want to do that?* - ans: homework)

```
function sum (a,b){
    if(b === undefined)
    {
        return function summer(next){
            return a + next;
        }
    }
    return a + b;
}
```

Upadted fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a8tds42d/2/

Comment: next here is the "8"  in sum(5)(8) , right ? its pretty simple and hard at the same time

Comment: yeah, you can resuse `b` as the other answer has, or you could use `arguments[0]` or, like I have you could use an entirely different var, just so its unambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

Just as another alternative:

```
function sum (a,b) { 
    if (b === undefined) { 
        return sum.bind(null, a); 
    } 
    return a + b; 
}
```

Using [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Partial_Functions) to curry.

Comment: wait.. what? I'm... yes. Erm... confused. (Works, of course!)

Comment: @Jamiec: `sum.bind` will, essentially, return a new function with `this` specified as null (not important in this case) and with it's first argument already bound to `a`. So all you need to do is specify `b`.

Comment: Yeah, I get it. I've just never thought of using it like that. Its a neat, if slightly obscure, trick.

Comment: @Jamiec: For a trivial case like this, you don't gain much from using `bind` to curry. But if the function is much more complex, it can save you rewriting a large potion of the function.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to write a curry function.  Kevin Ennis has shown in great details on how to implement one here.

https://medium.com/@kevincennis/currying-in-javascript-c66080543528

Here's the function from the above post (just in case the post goes away)

```
function curry( fn ) {
   var arity = fn.length;
   return (function resolver() {
      var memory = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments );
      return function() {
        var local = memory.slice(), next;
        Array.prototype.push.apply( local, arguments );
        next = local.length >= arity ? fn : resolver;
        return next.apply( null, local );
      };
   }());
}
```

And a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g4yoano4/)

Or you can use [Ramda.js](http://ramdajs.com) and here's to use Ramda

http://bit.ly/1IfaVM5